# How to draw many buttons for keyboard in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikeyboard

I want to draw 26 buttons for keyboard. There are 3 rows. First row has 10 button, second has 9, and the third has 7. The space from one button to another is 5. Each button has width: 27 and height: 40. How can I draw them at the same time ?

Comment: Could you give some sample code related ?

Comment: create a custom keyboard in xib using your own buttons

Comment: I don't use use xib, I want to draw by using code. I use loop, but it doesn't work !

Comment: How to loop with different letters in different row and column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can button like this:- it is not the solution of ur problem but.. u will still get the idea from that code.-

```
    objDelegate.redColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"255",@"215",@"242",@"198",@"204",@"119",@"217",@"149",@"112",@"79",@"247",@"55",@"0",@"0",@"255",@"16", nil];
    objDelegate.greenColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"255",@"228",@"220",@"217",@"193",@"147",@"150",@"179",@"48",@"98",@"150",@"96",@"0",@"176",@"0",@"37", nil];
    objDelegate.blueColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"255",@"189",@"219",@"241",@"218",@"60",@"148",@"215",@"160",@"40",@"70",@"146",@"0",@"80",@"0",@"63", nil];

    UIButton *btn[16];

    buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
   for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        btn[i] = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 15, 15)];

        [btn[i] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:[[objDelegate.redColorArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]/255.0 green:[[objDelegate.greenColorArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]/255.0 blue:[[objDelegate.blueColorArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]/255.0 alpha:1]];

        btn[i].tag = i;

        [btn[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(setColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [buttonArray addObject:btn[i]];

        [self addSubview:btn[i]];

        x+=20;

        if((i+1)%4==0)
        {
            x=0;
            y+=20;
       }
    }
```

it will show button like this
[image: Button image]